# Reference CTE inside CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I found this stored proc in our codebase:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MoveNodes]
(
    @id bigint,
    @left bigint,
    @right bigint,
    @parentid bigint,
    @offset bigint,
    @caseid bigint,
    @userid bigint

)
AS
BEGIN
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  id, parent, lft, rgt, title, type, caseid, userid, 0 AS level,
                CAST(LEFT(CAST(id AS VARCHAR) + REPLICATE('0', 10), 10) AS VARCHAR) AS bc
        FROM    [dbo].DM_FolderTree hc
        WHERE   id = @id and caseid = @caseid
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  hc.id, hc.parent, hc.lft, hc.rgt, hc.title, hc.type, hc.caseid, hc.userid, level + 1,
                CAST(bc + '.' + LEFT(CAST(hc.id AS VARCHAR) + REPLICATE('0', 10), 10) AS VARCHAR)
        FROM    q
        JOIN    [dbo].DM_FolderTree hc
        ON      hc.parent = q.id        
        )
UPDATE [dbo].DM_FolderTree 
    SET lft = ((-lft) + @offset), rgt = ((-rgt) + @offset), userid = @userid
    WHERE id in (select id from q) AND lft <= (-(@left)) AND rgt >= (-(@right)) AND caseid = @caseid;
UPDATE [dbo].DM_FolderTree SET parent = @parentid, userid = @userid WHERE id = @id AND caseid = @caseid;
END
```

where you'll notice that the CTE `q` is being used called on the `UNION`. What exactly are we calling here? Everything before the `UNION`, the whole CTE? What exactly is happening here.

I'm assuming that this code is legal, since its been in production for quite some time (FLW, I know). But still, I have no idea what's happening here.

Comment: This is a recursive query.  It calls the CTE again and again until all ID's and CaseIDs have walked the tree.  Think about nesting of folders in a directory.  This query simply walks all the directors to get final the "file path" for all files in all folders.  Notice how Level starts at 0 and then gets added to.  The second time though level is now 1 and becomes 2 and then 3 and so on.  Grab the select cte portion `(with q as...)` and replace the update with `Select * from q`  and run it.  Just so you can see how it works.

Comment: @xQbert Any reason for posting that as a comment? It seems like a decent answer to me.

Comment: Ok it's now an answer with some tweeks.  It just seemed not a programmatic question.

Comment: Yea, I wrestled with the idea of posting here, but I couldn't figure what other SE community would more appropriate... On that note, there was another question I had with this store proc. @xQbert could you take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34272534/2112866

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recursive query. It calls the CTE again and again until all ID's and CaseIDs have walked the tree.

Think about nesting of folders in a directory. This query simply walks all the directors to get final the "file path" for all files in all folders.

Notice how Level starts at 0 and then gets added to. The second time though level is now 1 and becomes 2 and then 3 and so on.

To better understand:

Grab the select cte portion `(with q as...)` and replace the update with `Select * from q` and run it. Just so you can see what it does.  Bit rough learning to start with but walking though an example by doing the above will help.

Specific answers to questions:

**What exactly are we calling here?**

Your building a baseline which denotes the all roots you wish to start with and then traversing all the levels under that root/folder.  So in essense you're crawling the entire structure for `hc.parent = q.id`

**Everything before the UNION, the whole CTE?**

The whole cte.  Recursion powerfully cool stuff!